# Put Sqlite data into two ListView inside two different Fragments

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments

Basically, I want to get data from Sqlite from two different table (or column) based on which Fragment is visible. I have already find a solution (tricky solution), and I want to know if there are other best way to reach the same result.I've founded a lot of tutorial only on a single Fragment. Below what I've done:

First of all, in my MainActivity I have:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hai cliccato la barra",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            if (fragment!=null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                ft.replace(R.id.screen_area,fragment);
                ft.commit();

            }
        }
    });
```

and from navigationView I can choose which fragment  I want to see:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

    }
    if (fragment!=null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.screen_area,fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id= item.getItemId();

    switch(id){

        case R.id.carburante:
            fragment = new CarburanteFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.giorni:
            fragment = new GiorniFragment();
            break;
```

...after that on my CarburanteFragment I pass the fragment to DbAdapter...for example in "Save":

```
private void save(String name)
    {
        DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(getActivity(),((MainActivity) getActivity()).fragment= this);
        db.openDB();
        boolean saved=db.add(name);
        if(saved)
        {
            nameEditText.setText("");
            this.getSpacecrafts();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Unable To Save",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

...finally in DBAdapter class I can get the fragment that I want to populate ListView....for example changing the Constants variable and so on....in the code below I tested only if it works:

```
 public DBAdapter(Context c,Fragment fr) {
    this.c = c;
    helper = new DBHelper(c);


  Fragment currentFragment =fr;
           if(currentFragment.getTag()=="carburante")
             Toast.makeText(c, currentFragment.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

Comment: I don't know if it make sense in your case. But, can you store a flag in your activity which hosts both the fragment and then use this flag the query db?

Comment: Or if you are showing the db data inside your fragment then you can query the db accordingly. Like if you have two fragments `HumansFrag` and `AnimalFrag`. Then query `HumansTable` inside `HumansFrag` and `AnimalTable` inside `AnimalFrag`

Comment: yes, I show data inside a ListView inside fragment....but I have two different fragment and respectively two different listView...the problem was how to choose from DB which data to load...my solution is above. Arnetatively I think that It's possible to load only one fragment and only one ListView and load inside it the correct data once that I know (maybe from button click) which kind of them I want......but at this time I don't know how to implement it :-)

Comment: While you are replacing the fragment, you can pass some data in bundle and set it as argument like `MyFrag frag = new MyFrag();` `Bundle bundle = new Bundle()` `bundle.put("FLAG", Constant.DATA1)` `frag.setArgument(bundle)` Then you can retrieve this argument in your and use this to identify which data you have to load.

Comment: I followed your tips...very useful...Thanks !

Comment: Since, your issue has been resolved, I have posted a solution to your question. Please mark it as the answer if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is you can pass a flag while replacing the fragment, which can be later used to identify which data you want to load.

For fragment1

```
Fragment1 frag = new Fragment1();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
bundle.put("MY_FLAG", 1);
frag.setArgument(bundle);
```

For fragment2

```
Fragment2 frag = new Fragment2();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
bundle.put("MY_FLAG", 2);
frag.setArgument(bundle);
```

Then you can use data in the flag to identify which type of data you want to load.